# Trying to run MOBSF but nothing appear

Tags: python, django, android-security

I am trying to work on MOBSF in order to test the security of specific mobile apps, I download the source and when I type `python manage.py runserver` I get access to the IP but all I get as in the picture, no images, colors or anything else. Please help how can I solve the problem?

MOBSF when run the server:
[image: MOBSF when run the server]

The error I get:
[image: The error I get]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, or pictures of error messages, or pictures of logs, or generally pictures of any kind of text. Text in pictures cannot be searched, text in pictures cannot be copypasted into an IDE, text in pictures cannot be copypasted into a web search engine, and text in pictures cannot be read by blind or otherwise visually impaired people. Just copy the text and paste it into your question as text. If you are unsure how to format it properly, don't worry, we can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, MobSF uses Python3.6+. However, there may  exist some other issues in Static or Dynamic analysis that you can report an issue in its [GitHub page](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF).

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you run latest versions of MobSF

In Windows:

```
setup.bat # to set up and configure MobSF
run.bat # to run MobSF
```

Always follow latest docs: https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF/wiki/1.-Documentation